# Bootstrap left side navbar won't collapse - Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm having trouble with my side navbar. I'd like for it to collapse upon click of my "fa-navicon", which should be placed to the right of the menu (and above the content).

I see the div area when I inspect the element in Chrome and Firefox, but it's completely blank and unclickable.

Here's my code:

```js
/* off-canvas sidebar toggle */
$('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
    $('.collapse').toggleClass('in').toggleClass('hidden-xs').toggleClass('visible-xs');
});
```

```css
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}

.wrapper, .row {
   height: 100%;
   margin-left:0;
   margin-right:0;
}

.wrapper:before, .wrapper:after,
.column:before, .column:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.wrapper:after,
.column:after {
    clear: both;
}

#sidebar {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding-left: 0;
    float: left;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#sidebar .collapse.in {
    display: inline;
}

#sidebar > .nav>li>a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main {
    padding: 15px;
    left: 0;
}

/*
 * off canvas sidebar
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        min-width: 44px;
    }
    
    #sidebar .visible-xs {
       display:inline !important;
    }
    
    .row-offcanvas {
       position: relative;
       -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
       transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .row-offcanvas-left.active {
       left: 45%;
    }
    
    .row-offcanvas-left.active .sidebar-offcanvas {
       left: -45%;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       width: 45%;
    }
} 
 
 
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 3%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active .sidebar-offcanvas {
    left: -3%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    min-width:42px;
  }
  
  #main {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.iamtonyalvarez.com/mysite/wp-content/themes/miami/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>


<!-- NAVBAR ON THE LEFT SIDE *** -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">


    <!-- sidebar -->
    <div class="column col-sm-3 col-xs-1 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
      <?php /* Primary navigation */
        wp_nav_menu( array(
          'menu' => 'top_menu',
          'depth' => 2,
          'container' => false,
          'menu_class' => 'nav',
          'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',  
          'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
      ?>
    </div>
<!-- /// NAVBAR ON THE LEFT SIDE *** -->

  
    <!--! BODY WRAPPER -->
    <div class="column col-sm-9 col-xs-11" id="main">
      <div>
         <a href="#" data-toggle="offcanvas"><i class="fa fa-navicon  fa-2x"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        ... Content ...
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the link to the page I'm trying to fix too:
[http://iamtonyalvarez.com/mysite/home-new](http://www.iamtonyalvarez.com/mysite/home-new)

Can anyone advise me on what I'm doing wrong? I can't seem to figure out why the menu icon won't appear and why it won't collapse.

Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You probably aren't loading Font-Awesome for your icons, `<i class="fa fa-navicon fa-2x"></i>`. See [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/).

Comment: @vanburen thx! I got the menu icon to appear. I can't believe I completely looked over that. However, I still have the non-working collapse issue. Any ideas?